# Jquery tablesorter sort via two fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have such html table:
here: http://jsfiddle.net/zrjaM/1/

And such js for sorting:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".sortable") 
    .tablesorter({sortList: [[4,0]], widgets: ['zebra']});
});
```

But i need to sort via 0-th column to.... i write:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".sortable") 
        .tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0],[4,0]], widgets: ['zebra']});
    });
```

but it works strange...

Also i need to do that, tr's with price value (4-th column) are on top, but now, when i sort only by price - all is ok, but when via two columns, i could have tr's with price both in end or middle.... How to send them to top, and sort first via 0-th, then via sorter 0-th sort via 4-t column.... How to do it?

Comment: demo doesn't do much good without plugin included and initialization script. How are we to see what the problem is?

Comment: @charlietfl update fiddle.... but there it doesn't sort, don't know why

Comment: syntax problem , missing comma, should be `[[0,0],[4,0]]`. You have 2 `tbody` which is problem. Not sure what sorting issues are. Code works as expected http://jsfiddle.net/zrjaM/3/  The second sort of price will only change items in first column with same value. Not sure what you are expecting. If you need more advanced filtering look at `datatables.js`

Comment: @charlietfl (,) that is not the problem... Read question.... All tr with price must go to top, now i see sorting that different tr's are in table, but i must see sorting as now, but tr's with price must go on top (and be sorted there...)  Also note, that i must have my styling, without any sorting via click...'

Comment: then you need to be very explicit what sort should look like. Just saying prices should be at top throws off alphabetic sort on left like this http://jsfiddle.net/zrjaM/5/ Would hiding rows with no price help? Or could move to another table ...top table has price, bottom table doesn't

Comment: @charlietfl using my haml view dont't edit any tables.... only if in js, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a possible solution.

First check rows for no price, if no price add a hidden span before item name in first column the text `ZZZZZZZ` in it. This forces all the `ZZZZZZZ` items to bottom and you get a double sort alphabetic on first row

```
$('tbody tr').each(function(){
    if( $.trim( $(this).find('td').eq(4).text())==''){
       $(this).find('td').eq(0).prepend('<span style="display:none">ZZZZZZZZ</span>')
       }
});

$(".sortable") .tablesorter({
      sortList: [[0,0],[4,0]], widgets: ['zebra']});
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/zrjaM/6/

Answer (score 2):

@charlietfl's solution would work even without the code to add `ZZZZZZZ` to empty cells. But because that demo is using the original version of tablesorter, the first tbody would have to be removed.

But, because it looks like you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/), which does allow [sorting multiple tbodies](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-multiple-tbodies.html), all you need to do is set the [`emptyTo` option](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/#emptyto) to `none`.

The `emptyTo` option is set to `bottom` by default. So all empty cells will always sort to the bottom. The reason the third column doesn't look like it's sorting at all is because all links in that column have the same text. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/363/).

Update: also remove the `tablesorter-headerSortDown` from the fourth column, it's still in the css but the plugin is using `tablesorter-headerDesc` now.